# Data Structure for Math formulae

Tags: python, math, pylatex

I am working on a python script that generates pdfs for math-tests via pylatex.
So far I am using

```
str(random.randint(8,32)) +' + ' + str(random.randint(8,121))
```

and similar for generating randomized assignments.

I don't want to hard-code everything like above but I want to use a database approach to store possible assignments.
My idea in this direction is a relational database

```
(student) --n (assignment_type)
```

where the students each get personilized assignments, for instance Peter will get assigments of the type

```
( (random sign) (random number 2-8) x (+ or -) (random sign) (random number))    (*)
```

and

```
( (random number 2323-9999):11)
```

I am unsure on how to save this datastructure in a database and how to translate it into python code.
My idea here is for the database table 'assignment_type':

```
INT number of randomized vars
INT number of signs
ARRAY List of signs
ARRAY (lower und upper bound for each random number)
STRING '(s1r1s2r1)'
```

Where '(s1r1s2(s3r1))' would be translated in python to the above problem (*) ("( sign1 random1 sign2 (sign3)random2)")
I am very unsure if this way of handling the problem is a stupid idea. I ask you hereby to review my approach and if possible point me in a better direction of handling this kind of data-structure.

Answer (score 0):

A quick idea:

First, define a few random functions for later use.

```py
import random

def sign_num(a, b):
  n = random.randint(a, b)
  if random.random() < 0.5:
    return '(-{})'.format(n)
  else:
    return str(n)

def num(a, b):
  return str(random.randint(a,b))

def add(a, b, parens=False):
  n1 = num(a, b)
  n2 = num(a, b)
  if parens:
    return '({} + {})'.format(n1, n2)
  else:
    return '{} + {}'.format(n1, n2)

def sign_add(a, b, parens=False):
  n1 = sign_num(a, b)
  n2 = sign_num(a, b)
  if parens:
    return '({} + {})'.format(n1, n2)
  else:
    return '{} + {}'.format(n1, n2)
```

Then, make a `dict` with reference to all these functions:

```py
dico = {'NUM': num, 'SIGNNUM': sign_num, 'ADD': add, 'SIGN_ADD': sign_add}
```

Then, write your parsing functions:

```py
def fill_in(txt):
  argv = txt.strip().split()
  return dico[argv[0]](int(argv[1]), int(argv[2]))

def parse(txt):
  if '[' not in txt:
    return txt
  else:
    i = txt.index('[')
    j = txt.index(']')
    return txt[:i] + fill_in(txt[i+1:j])  + parse(txt[j+1:])
```

Now you can call them on template strings:

```py
parse('[NUM 3 9] x ([ADD 2 9])')
# '8 x (8 + 7)'
```

There is a ton of room for improvement. In particular, the function `fill_in` should be written in a way that handles variable number of arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed answer. Nice to see some python-magic with dicts and templates.